# Need to filter lines from a sequence but keep it as a single sequence

Tags: kotlin, java-stream, sequence

I need to read a file from disk, filter out some rows based on conditions, then return the result as a **single stream/sequence, not a sequence of strings**.  The file is too large to hold in memory all at once, so it must be treated as a Stream/Sequence throughout processing.  This is what I tried.

```kotlin
File(filename).bufferedReader()
   // break into lines
   .lineSequence()
   // filter each line based on condition
   .filter{meetsSomeCondition(it)}
   // add newline back in
   .map{(it+"\n").byteInputStream()} 
   // reduce back into a single stream with Java's SequenceInputStream
   .reduce<InputStream, ByteArrayInputStream> { acc, i -> SequenceInputStream(acc, i) }
```

This works when testing on a small file, but when using a large file it errors with a `StackOverFlow` exception.  It seems that Java's `SequenceInputStream` can't handle repeatedly nesting itself like I do with the `reduce` call.

I see that `SequenceInputStream` also has a way of accepting an `Enumeration` argument that takes a **List** of elements.  But that's the problem, as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to accept a `Stream`.

Comment: `reduce` is a terminal sequence operator, which means it immediately iterates the entire sequence to produce its output, so even if `SequenceInputStream` allowed deep nesting of itself, the `reduce` line would have to read the whole file into memory all at once to produce the final stream. Is there any reason you can't use a `Sequence<ByteArray>`?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement for *not a sequence of strings*, this does not seem to violate your actual requirements. Having a sequence of strings is exactly what you get with `lineSequence()` and it's not a problem at all (it definitely does NOT read the whole file in memory). Having a sequence of strings also is a single sequence, so there is no reason to oppose "a sequence of strings" with "a single sequence". If what you want is bytes, then it's ok. But if your reasons are the ones mentioned, I suggest you do keep a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not really do what you think it does. `reduce()` is a terminal operation, meaning that it consumes all elements in the sequence. After `reduce()` line the whole file has been read already. Also, it is not `SequenceInputStream` that does not support such reduce operation. You created a very long chain of objects. `SequenceInputStream` objects does not really know they were chained like this and they can't do too much about it.

Instead, you need to keep a sequence "alive" and create an `InputStream` that will read from the source sequence whenever required. I don't think there is an utility like this in the stdlib. It is a very specialized requirement.

The easiest is to create a sequence of bytes and then provide `InputStream` which reads from it:

```kotlin
File(filename).bufferedReader()
   .lineSequence()
   .filter{meetsSomeCondition(it)}
   .flatMap { "$it\n".toByteArray().asIterable() }
   .asInputStream()

fun Sequence<Byte>.asInputStream() = object : InputStream() {
    val iter = iterator()
    override fun read() = if (iter.hasNext()) iter.next().toUByte().toInt() else -1
}
```

However, sequence of bytes isn't really the best for performance. We can optimize it by reading line by line, so creating a sequence of strings or byte arrays:

```kotlin
File(filename).bufferedReader()
   .lineSequence()
   .filter{meetsSomeCondition(it)}
   .map { "$it\n".toByteArray() }
   .asInputStream()

fun Sequence<ByteArray>.asInputStream() = object : InputStream() {
    val iter = iterator()
    var curr = iter.next()
    var pos = 0

    override fun read(): Int {
        return when {
            pos < curr.size -> curr[pos++].toUByte().toInt()
            !iter.hasNext() -> -1
            else -> {
                curr = iter.next()
                pos = 0
                read()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note this implementation of `asInputStream()` will fail for empty sequence)

Still, there is much room for improvement regarding the performance. We read from sequence line by line, but we still read from `InputStream` byte by byte. To improve it further we would need to implement more methods of `InputStream` to read in bigger chunks. If you really care about the performance then I suggest looking into `BufferedInputStream` implementation and try to re-use some of its codebase.

Also, remember to close the file reader that was created in the first step. It won't close automatically when `InputStream` will be closed.